# What's the alogrithm for insert before/after the first node for a circular doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, deque

I've been building a deque by using tail pointer, and I just wonder if the algorithm would be the same if I use circular pointers. In my opinion, I won't have to keep track of the tail pointer anymore, and it'd be easier to maintain and update the list. However, it also strucks me that the insert before/after the first node would be pretty much the same, since it's a circle, it does not make a different between first of after. Is my understanding correct? Would be great if you can demonstrate an example here or show the pseudo code for these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code to insert a node before/after the head. If thats what you're looking for.

```
struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
};

bool insert_after_head(struct node *head, int val)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        return false;

    struct node *temp = new node;
    if(temp == NULL)
        return false;

    temp->val = val;

    // build new links
    temp->prev = head;
    temp->next = head->next;

    // rebuild old links(watch the order)   
    head->next->prev = temp;
    head->next = temp;

    return true;
}

bool insert_before_head(struct node *head, int val)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        return false;

    struct node *temp = new node;
    if(temp == NULL)
        return false;

    temp->val = val;

    // build new links
    temp->next = head;
    temp->prev = head->prev;

    // rebuild old links(watch the order)
    head->prev->next = temp;
    head->prev = temp;

    return true;
}
```